# Implementing Jquery Pagination to Opencart Admin page

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to add jquery pagination plugin to opencart Admin page(Catalog > Options > Option value)( `/admin/view/template/catalog/option_form.tpl` ).

When you click on edit option it loads option values. I have lots of those that is why I am trying to implement paging.

I tried many jquery plugins but to no avail as the plugins have no effect.

Is there any way I can implement paging using jquery or is there any other method i can use?

Thanks.

[Edit]

Whatever i know i tried in php and it is not working.

```
  EDIT:
```

I tried one more thing: 
in `admin/controller/catalog/product/option.php`

in the method:
`public function edit() {`

I added this code:

```
<code>

    $pagination = new Pagination();
    $pagination->total = $option_value_total;
    $pagination->page = $page;
    $pagination->limit = $this->config->get('config_limit_admin');
    $pagination->url = $this->url->link('catalog/option/edit', 'token='     . $this->session->data['token'] . $url . '&page={page}', 'SSL');

    $data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();

    $data['results'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_pagination'), ($option_value_total) ? (($page - 1) 
                        * $this->config->get('config_limit_admin')) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) 
                        * $this->config->get('config_limit_admin')) > ($option_total - $this->config->get('config_limit_admin'))) ? $option_value_total : ((($page - 1) 
                        * $this->config->get('config_limit_admin')) 
                        + $this->config->get('config_limit_admin')), $option_value_total, ceil($option_value_total / $this->config->get('config_limit_admin')));

</code>
In Option_form.tpl
<code> 

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-left"><?php echo $pagination; ?></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right"><?php echo $results; ?></div>
    </div>

</code>
In admin/model option.php

in <code>public function getOptionValues($option_id) {</code> I added 
<code> 

    if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {
        if ($data['start'] < 0) {
        $data['start'] = 0;
        }

        if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
        $data['limit'] = 20;
        }

        $sql .= " LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit'];
        }

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        return $query->rows;

</code>
```

Comment: Why not use the default OC pagination?

Comment: Pagination is not implemented for options values. (option_form). Not that i know of.

Comment: But it's build in the system, so it should be easier to apply than any third party. Using third parties should also be reasonably easy but there is no out of the box solution for that.

Comment: i didnt understand. I am talking about pagination to option values.for example I have Color Option with 1000 option values. When on Admin, Go to Catalog > Options. Click Edit on Color option. When you click edit, it shows all 1000 values in the same page. What i want to do is to see only few like 10 on 1 page, so we can use paging.

Comment: Yes I understood that, and it's duable, you need to change the controller, template and possibly the model, but as I said there is no easy way to explain it without making most of the code to show you.

Comment: Oh. okay. Is there any other way than php? Like jquery? I dont know php so I cannot create in that. I added what I did to change in the main post.

Comment: can you please check if i am missing something in the code. i edited the question and added what i tried.

Comment: @SyedMudabbir you can do it like yoda saying, if you don't know php or don't want in it then add your jquery/ js code here

Comment: @user5419232 I tried using php/javascript and built in pagination also but the issue remains that once you open that option, the option values only displayed on the current view is being saved rest of the option values are destroyed. So i am guessing it is not possible to give pagination to option values

Comment: @SyedMudabbir yes, this is the issue. You can save all values to hidden input but these are just tricks, it can increase code and have to change in various file. OC Structure is not build to do these type of things. Sorry :(

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? I am having the same issue